# Cannot access member for type tuple[Any, ...] using Pandas DataFrame itertuples (Pyright-langserver with Neovim 0.7)

Tags: pandas, neovim, pyright

I'm using the pyright-langserver with Neovim v0.7.0. It functions well, except I don't know how to correctly annotate the types in the following situation.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [4, 2], 'num_wings': [0, 2]},index=['dog', 'hawk'])

for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.num_legs) # ■ Cannot access member "num_legs" for type "tuple[Any, ...]"    Member "num_legs" is unknown
```

As you can see, I put a comment showing the error that pyright reports: `Cannot access member "num_legs" for type "tuple[Any, ...]"    Member "num_legs" is unknown`

The code is valid in that it prints 4, then 2, as I would expect. How do I satisfy the type-checking?

Comment: @creanion thanks for your reply. That issue doesn't really answer the question. We have two people saying they _think_ it's impossible to provide type hints, which I can accept if it's true. But even still, is there some way to silence this error message which is coming from the language server?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a solution to fix the type issue (Pandas just types as a generic tuple), but there are at least two ways to suppress the error reports.

1. Tell Pyright to [ignore the error](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/comments.md):

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.num_legs)  # # pyright: ignore [reportGeneralTypeIssues]
```

2. [cast()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the type to Any to turn off type interference for the object

```
from typing import cast

for row in df.itertuples():
    row: Any = cast(Any, row)
    print(row.num_legs)
```